# Genexus Report with Embedded BLOB (PDF) files

Tags: pdf, report, blob, genexus

i'm trying to create a PDF report object that contains some PDF files saved as BLOB records into my DB.

At this point I'm able to embed images only...

How can I "append" other kinds of files into my genexus-report, such as PDF files?

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Client: GXEv2 - U5,
Environment: Java

Answer (score 0):

I know it's possible to append others GX reports in your report by calling them.
However, i think there is no way to append a PDF file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope to find a solution, maybe with Artech support